# Theano printing probabilities for test-set samples

Tags: generics, printing, types, probability, theano

in DL tutorials I'm trying to print the probability of the test samples according to   [What is the prupose/meaning of passing "input" to a function in Theano?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323040/what-is-the-prupose-meaning-of-passing-input-to-a-function-in-theano)
but I get the following Error. Do I need to add some theano_flags?

how to solve the problem?

> TypeError: Cannot convert Type Generic (of Variable ) into
>   Type TensorType(float64, matrix). You can try to manually convert
>    into a TensorType(float64, matrix).
>
> (number of features of my data=120,classes=2,test_set batch size=1)

part of the code is:

from theano import pp

```
classifier = LogisticRegression(input=x, n_in=120, n_out=2)

print " Theano builds graphs for the expressions it computes before evaluating them:that is..."
print pp(classifier.p_y_given_x)

             .........................


     # test it on the test set

                test_losses = [test_model(i)
                               for i in xrange(n_test_batches)]
                test_score = numpy.mean(test_losses)


                values=theano.shared(value=test_set_x.get_value)
                f=theano.function([],classifier.p_y_given_x, 
                                  givens={x:values},on_unused_input='ignore')
                print f()
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in your code when you create values. test_set_x.get_value is a python function. So it should be test_set_x.get_value() as you want the value, not the callable that return it. As theano.shared() receive as input a callable, it create a generic Theano varible that isn't a tensor. So when you try to replace x that is a tensor variable with a generic variable, it raise an error as it is not an allowed  replacement.

But even better, you don't need to create a new shared variable, just compile the function like this:

```
            f=theano.function([],classifier.p_y_given_x, 
                              givens={x:test_set_x},on_unused_input='ignore')
```

Comment: Thanks!!I tried in LogisticRegression and logistic_sgd and this finally worked!  However I wonder, when applying this method to DBN or SdA,first I specify a dbn or sda as a classifier and then call the p_y_given_x from the logistic class and define as a function? since the DBN/SdA class only deals with test errors...?

Comment: ***when I try to print the probabilities of the test_set in DBN.py as follows;by adding (just befor the print statement in the end of test_DBN())classifier=dbn.logLayer(input=dbn.x,n_in=120,n_out=2)
f=theano.function([],classifier.p_y_given_x,
                          givens={dbn.x:test_set_x},
                          on_unused_input='ignore')
print f()   =====It gives me an error " classifier=dbn.logLayer(input=dbn.x,n_in=120,n_out=2)
TypeError: 'LogisticRegression' object is not callable" do I need to _def_p_y_given_x in logistic_sgd?